# Is there a was we can pass mailchimp HTML template for campaign broadcast

Tags: .net, api, mailchimp

We have a blog website and when ever we have a new blog we send out a newsletter to the subscribed users. At present we have to create new template each time with text and images before we can broadcast it. This process in itself take time.

Is there a way using mailchimp API we can pass HTML template to mail chimp and initiate the newsletter broadcast.

HTML template would be created dynamically each time new blog is added to the website, rather than we spend 1 hours creating or replicating & then updated template with new images, text and links etc.

Want to know if this can be managed programmatically using .net

Answer (score 1):

The MailChimp API does support what you're looking for. Check out the [campaign creation docs](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#create-post_campaigns). That said, an easier solution to your problem is probably to just use your blog's RSS feed and set up an [RSS Campaign](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/rss-in-campaigns/create-an-rss-campaign) and automate the whole thing without writing any code.